# Soluble yeast estimation before carbonation

Tags: beer, yeast, cider, residual

### Any suggestions on how to estimate the amount of yeast that remains in the brew solution after standard transfer practices without using clarification? I know that some remain because of priming carbonation before bottling.

edit to clarify: I am wondering if the amount that is actually consumed is negligible in terms of nutritional information.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what sort of metric are you looking for here, and why do you want to estimate it?

Comment: Adding as a comment since I'm not strictly answering your question: If you are really asking: "Will there be enough yeast to carbonate my beer by bottle conditioning?" The answer is almost certainly "yes."  Alternatively, you may be asking: "Am I drinking a lot of yeast?" and the answer is also almost certainly "yes," unless you allow it to clear for a long time.

Comment: @dustin - neither is the question that I am asking. I want to know the amount of yeast that remains in solution. Clearly there is some, that is why carbonation occurs after priming before bottling. This is true even with clarification techniques such as gelatin. "A lot" doesn't really say much, compared to the amount that is added during primary fermentation.

Comment: @pjreddie - grams would be nice, trying to work up a more detailed nutritional analysis and wondered if in these terms, it is negligible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of yeast in grams/l will most likely be negligible. If you want to now exactly how much yeast is in your beer, you have to do cell counting, which is a bit involved and requires a microscope plus additional equipment. [White Labs has a description](http://www.whitelabs.com/beer/cell_count.html) of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From a pure estimation stand point it will vary too much batch to batch.  If you let a batch sit a week longer than your last batch more yeast will have flocculated out.  If you use a highly flocculating strain you'll have less than a poor flocculated.  Temperature and vibrations from the environment will effect the sedimentation rate.
The only way to know is to count it with a scope and hemacytometer.